# Same resource for multiple routes - EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like use routes like:

```
/seller
/seller/
/seller/123
/seller/456
```

I define my route-setup like this:

```
this.route('seller', { path: '/seller' });
this.route('seller', { path: '/seller/:sellerId' });
```

In other words, I would like to use the same controller for these two routes, this works fine when I call route directly in browser but when I call

```
get(this,'router').transitionTo('seller', id);
```

Ocurrs a warning(I will update the question with the error that occurs), probaly because is the same name of controller.... What I can do?

Comment: Can you add the functionality you want to share between these controllers? I don't think you'll be able to use the same route name for two things, but maybe we can help you create two controllers that have the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use one controller for each route.
Sharing resources usually is done with services, mixins, data store or local storage.

My approach would be to create a service which loads the resource and saves it.
Both controllers import the service and have access to the same resource.